# How can I filter multiple columns that include the same value in Power BI?

Tags: database, powerbi, relational-database, relationship

I currently have a table in Power BI named `Jira Tickets`.

Here is sample data from `Jira Tickets`:

| Issue id | Label | Label 1 | Label 2 | Label 3 | Label 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Apples | Grapes | Bananas | Oranges | Strawberries |
| 1001 | Oranges | Pears | Apples | Bananas | Strawberries |
| 1002 | Pears | Dragon Fruit | Apples | Strawberries | Dragon Fruit |
| 1003 | Bananas | Oranges | Apples | Grapes | Pears |
| 1004 | Grapes | Apples | Bananas | Pears | Strawberries |

I want to create a slicer in Power Bi to filter by the column values in `Label` `Label 1` `Label 2` `Label 3` `Label 4`. The issue is that this gets confusing when choosing which column value to filter by, as the same column value exists within different columns. For example, If I wanted to filter by `Apples`, I would need to select multiple `Apples` values from `Label` `Label 1` `Label 2` and `Label 4`.

How can I create a slicer in Power BI to ensure I can filter uniquely by:
`Apples`
`Oranges`
`Pears`
`Bananas`
`Strawberries`
`Dragon Fruit`
`Grapes`?

Comment: Unpivot the data first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create disconnected table for alllabel:

[image]

```
AllLabel = SUMMARIZE(UNION(VALUES(Fruit[Label 1]), VALUES(Fruit[Label 2]), VALUES(Fruit[Label 3]), VALUES(Fruit[Label 4])),Fruit[Label 1])
```

Create a measure:

```
PickThis = 
var _selectedFruit = SELECTEDVALUE(AllLabel[Label 1])
return
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Fruit) , FILTER(Fruit,Fruit[Label 1] = _selectedFruit || Fruit[Label 2] = _selectedFruit || Fruit[Label 3] = _selectedFruit || Fruit[Label 4] = _selectedFruit))
```

Add measure to your visualization (or to filter):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this has filtered the Slicer so there is no duplicates within the Slicer, but when I click a value "Oranges" it does not change any of the data on the other visuals connected to the table "Fruit". Would I need to make a relationship between the two?

Comment: its depend on your model. If you can filter "other" table by one column by label then use relationship;

Comment: Relationship between which two columns on which tables?

Comment: I am unable to answer. I don't know your data model.

Comment: I have added the data model to the question